# Cannot import module from Cypress spec file

Tags: automation, automated-tests, cypress

I am trying to use the `@peculiar/x509` library to decode a CSR to use some of the information in my tests. The tests are using Cypress.

Here is an extract of my code:

```js
import * as x509 from '@peculiar/x509';
    
const request = {
  certificateSigningRequest: `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----`,
};
    
describe('PKI', () => { 
  it('works', () => {
    console.log(x509);
    const stringPEM = request.certificateSigningRequest
      .replace(/(-----(BEGIN|END) CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----|\n)/g, "");
    const cert = new x509.X509Certificate(stringPEM);
    console.log(cert.subject);
    
    return;
    // Stuff I want to test
  });    
});
```

When I try to log the x509 variable it returns an empty object.
And on the `const cert = new x509.X509Certificate(stringPEM);` line, I get an error:

```
x509.X509Certificate is not a constructor.
```

If I try to set up a simple project with a Typescript file to import the library and just log the `x509` variable, it displays all the exports correctly.

I can't figure why it behaves like that with Cypress, so any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Diving a bit more into how Cypress works, I now understand that my assumption about the spec files running/controlled in a Node process was wrong. Spec files are running in the browser. So I would need to inject the browser version of the library in the spec file.
This can be done via the plugin API of Cypress, because it runs in the Cypress node process.

Comment: It could be a nodejs version issue. @peculiar/x509 requires 14.x, 15.x

Comment: My NodeJS version is 14.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import a specific build, either `x509.es.js` or `x509.cjs.js` and your code works. The base `@peculiar/x509` is for `<script>` inclusion.

One thing, the BEGIN and END tokens need to remain in the request for it to be recognized.

```js
import * as x509 from '@peculiar/x509/build/x509.es.js'
// const x509 = require('@peculiar/x509/build/x509.cjs.js')  // alternative

// hard left for multiline strings, otherwise request is not correctly formatted
const request = {
  certificateSigningRequest: `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----`,
};

// copied from @peculiar/x509 to verify format - not necessary for test
const isPem = (data) => {
  return typeof data === "string"
    && /-{5}BEGIN [A-Z0-9 ]+-{5}([a-zA-Z0-9=+/\n\r]+)-{5}END [A-Z0-9 ]+-{5}/g.test(data);
}
console.log(isPem(request.certificateSigningRequest))

describe('PKI', () => {

  it('works', () => {
    console.log(x509);
    const stringPEM = request.certificateSigningRequest // leave in BEGIN and END
    const cert = new x509.X509Certificate(stringPEM);
    console.log(cert.subject);    // prints e.g. "CN=Test certificate, E=some@email.net"

    return;
    // Stuff I want to test
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly due to NodeJS version issue.

The `X509Certificate` was added recently in NodeJS version `15.6.0`. [Changelog here](https://nodejs.org/ko/blog/release/v15.6.0/). So it requires that version. It might have worked on your simple project because of a newer NodeJS version.

And by default, Cypress is using its bundled NodeJS version, which since Cypress version `7.0.0` to `8.2.0`, it's using bundled NodeJS version `14.16.0`, as per the [changelog here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/changelog#7-0-0):

> The bundled Node.js version was upgraded from `12.18.3` to `14.16.0`.

So you can try changing/overriding the bundled NodeJS version in Cypress configuration to version `15.6.0`, as per this [configuration](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Node-version):

`nodeVersion`

Comment: The X509Certificate comes from the @peculiar/x509 library. Not the one from NodeJS.